# Does cuDNN library works with All nvidia graphic cards?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, gpu

I study the use of cuDNN library in my project. But my nvidia graphic card is little bit old.

I search on the net if cuDNN works with all graphic cards. I didn,t find even in their principal page.

Which nvidia graphic cards are compatible with cuDNN?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kepler and newer, ie compute capability 3.0 and above.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

> Supported on Windows, Linux and MacOS systems with Pascal, Kepler, Maxwell, Tegra K1 or Tegra X1 GPUs.

Answer (score 6):

The [deep learning SDK documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/) also<sup>(1)</sup> contains relevant information on the requirements to run cuDNN.

There you will find a link to the list of current GPUs and their compute capabilities,  from which you can select the graphic card having the required **compute capability >=3.0** <sup>(2)</sup>:

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Here is an excerpt for GeForce cards:
[image]

Wikipedia has this even more convenient [CUDA supported GPU table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported) listing most (if not all) NVDIA graphic cards with their compute capabilities (the most up-to-date information is however likely to be found from the NVDIA link on cuda-gpus above).

<sub>(1) in reference to Robert Crovella's answer</sub>

<sup>(2) as of May 2018</sup>